# Generate random port traffic windows

Tags: windows, ports

Without installing any third party software is there a way to generate random traffic for a port of choice in Windows 2003?

I'm testing a few Port Forwards and just need some random test data. I'd usually use NetCat if it was Linux but can't do so in Windows as it isn't native.

Comment: Telnet (on the default install disk, but not enabled by default) will allows 'telnet test.mydomain.foo 4444'. Or you could try to open a webpage via a browser. (e.g. open IE and enter the page 'http://test.mydomain.foo:4444'). Both of these nor ping (aka ICMP echo request in the other suggestion) will not send RANDOM data though.    I can come up with some random data programs, but not without installing additional software.

Comment: Grah! I wrote  H T T P  COLON slash slah   test.mydomain.foo:4444. The 'helpful' website seems to remove this.